# Should "aspect" be a synonym for the "вид" tag?

Tags: discussion

Should "aspect" be a synonym for the "вид" tag?

I don't have enough reputation to suggest synonyms, but it seems like it would make sense for those who do not know the names of grammatical terms in Russian, but only in English.

Comment: Do you still have not enough reputation to do that? Maybe adding `tag-synonyms` tag and/or `feature-request` will help to resolve this query?