# Is there a list of bilingual tag synonyms on the site that need to be merged? Can we create one?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, proposal

To commemorate [the Moscow subway now also making announcements in English](https://news.rambler.ru/moscow_city/36746622-vse-stantsii-moskovskogo-metro-i-mtsk-nachali-obyavlyat-na-angliyskom-yazyke/), I suggest that we merge all existing Russian-language tags with English synonyms and vice versa.

This is a follow-up to two of my previous meta questions: [(1)](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/should-aspect-be-a-synonym-for-the-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4-tag)[(2)](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6-tag-should-all-tags-be-associated-with-their-english-transl).

The 'accusative' and 'винительный-падеж' tags were already merged thankfully.

However, there are tags corresponding to even more common grammatical terms for which the English and Russian terms are still not tag synonyms. For example:

- `глаголы` and `verbs`  (**most important one by far, imo**)
- `вид` and `aspect`
- `спряжение` and the non-existent `conjugation` tag.
- `множественное-число` and non-existent `plurals` or `number` tags. (Although `number` would go better with `число`, so we could also have `singular` and `единственное-число`.)
- `родительный-падеж` and non-existent `genitive` tag.
- `ударение` and `stress`.
- `алфавит` and non-existent `alphabet` tag.
- `история-языка` and non-existent `language-history` or `history` tags.
- `лингвистика` and non-existent `linguistics` tag.
- `лексикон` and non-existent `lexicon` tag.
- `глаголы-движения` and non-existent `movement` or `verbs-of-movement` or `verbs-of-motion` tags.
- `этнонимы` and non-existent `ethnonyms` tag.
- `значение` needs to be merged with `значения` and `meaning`.
- `словарь` and `dictionary` need to be merged.
- `культура` and the non-existent `culture`.
- `словообразование` and the non-existent `morphological-derivation`.
- `буква-ё` and the non-existent `yo` or `e-with-diaresis` or something like that.
- `словоупотребление` and `usage` need to be merged.
- `пунктуация` and `punctuation` need to be merged.
- `пословица` and non-existent `proverbs`.
- `транскрипция` and perhaps (as of yet non-existent) `transcription` or the already-in-use `transliteration.`
- `formality` should perhaps be merged with `этикет`.
- `заимстования` and the non-existent `borrowings`.
- `психолингвистика` and the non-existent `psycholinguistics`.
- `переходность` and `transitivity` need to be merged.
- `quote` and the non-existent `цитата`
- `oblique subject` and whatever the translation into Russian is.
- `word-order` and non-existent [`типология-порядка-слов`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).
- `swearing` and non-existent `матерна` or `мат`.
- `software` and non-existent `программное-обеспечение`.
- `russian-usage` and non-existent [`русский-язык-в-мире`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5).
- `vocabulary` and non-existent [`словарный-запас`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81).
- `phrase` needs to be merged with `выражения` or with a new (as of yet non-existent) tag `фразы`.
- `idioms` needs to be merged with `пословица` or a new (as of yet non-existent) tag `идиомы`.
- `suffixes` and the non-existent `суффиксы`.
- `infinitive` and the non-existent `инфинитив`.
- `other-languages` and the non-existent `другие-языки`.
- `interjection` and the non-existent `междометие`.
- `ukrainian` and the non-existent `украинский-язык`.
- `slang` and the non-existent `сленг` or `разговорная-речь` or  `просторечие` ([source](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3)).
- `dative` and the non-existent `дательный-падеж`.
- `slavic` and the non-existent `славянские языки`. (Maybe also `ukrainian` and `украинский-язык` should be merged with this as well, or maybe this should be merged with `other-languages` and `другие-языки`.)
- `belorussian` and the non-existent `белорусский-язык`.
- `objects` and the non-existent `дополнения`.

These were the only ones I could find, but I am sure that there are more.

Answer (score 1):

We've created (and merged) most of the proposed tag synonyms.
Right now almost all of the master synonyms are in Russian:

> plurals → множественное-число
>   suffixes → суффиксы

This is a point to discuss.
Please don't hesitate to share your opinion on the synonyms direction.

Comment: _This is a point to discuss._ Should the discussion be here or at another (existing/to be created) Meta question?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Here. But if you have another question, please ask it separately.